Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content. (Filament & Laravel)
I was trying to install Filament into my Laravel project, and this happened. Could it be because of a version conflict?
PHP: v8.2.12
Laravel: v11.8.0
Error Message:
To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
- C:\xampp\php\php.ini
You can also run php --ini in a terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
Alternatively, you can run Composer with --ignore-platform-req=ext-intl to temporarily ignore these required extensions.
Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.

This was the command I entered in the terminal.
composer require filament/filament:"^3.2" -W

It tells you in the error that ext-intl is missing and that you need to install it or enable it.

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors, images are hard to read and troubleshoot. Please [edit] your post and add the information here as text. Be sure to take the [tour] and read [ask].

"Could it be because of a version conflict?" - no. Did you actually read the error message? What did you try to resolve it?

@NicoHaase I did run php --ini and see the path of my php.ini but I still don't know how to enable this extensions ?
